# Compare metrics counter value for the last two successive 5 min intervals (prometheus ql)

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a counter which is growing each time some server logic succeeds. I'm trying to write an expression that will evaluate in percents the counter value difference between the last 5 minutes and the previous 5 minutes intervals. And if the difference is more than 50% I should alert that. So I guess I need to evaluate each 5 min interval's value and just compare the two successive of them. So far I'm trying to use this query:

```
increase(my_counter_metric[10m]) - increase(my_counter_metric[5m]) / increase(my_counter_metric[10m]) * 100 > 50
```

But I guess such query can be optimized somehow. Is there a better way of doing the same logic or am I totally wrong using such query for my goal? I'm afraid that in the case of server restart or if `increase(...[10m])` will be `0` the expression would fail with error (i.e. `division by 0`). Can I avoid such cases somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [offset modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier). For example, the following query returns non-empty result (e.g. it triggers the alert) if the counter increased over the last 5 minutes by less than 50% comparing to the counter increase over the last 5 minutes ending 5 minutes ago:

```
increase(my_counter_metric[5m] offset 5m) / increase(my_counter_metric[5m]) < 0.5
```

As for the protection against division by zero, the following query can be used:

```
(
  increase(my_counter_metric[5m] offset 5m) / increase(my_counter_metric[5m]) < 0.5
) and (increase(my_counter_metric[5m])) != 0)
```

It uses the [and](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) operator for filtering out results if the denominator equals zero. Otherwise an empty result is returned, which doesn't trigger the alert.